# Streamlit AGGrid: text alignment in the header is weird

Tags: ag-grid, streamlit

I'm using the latest version of streamlit-aggrid to render a simple list, but the text alignment in the header is weird - first half (SKU to Category) to the left of the cell and second half (overall to info quality) to the right of the cell:

[image]

I didn't explicitly config these, just using default for most configs. What could be a cause to this?

```
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(my_data)

gb.configure_default_column(
        filterable=False,
        groupable=False,
        editable=False,
        wrapText=True,
        autoWidth=False,
    )

AgGrid(
            my_data,
            gridOptions=gb.build(),
            fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
            custom_css=custom_css,
            allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
        )
```